# Can't retrieve text from MySQL DB

Tags: php, html

i've created a simple blog system which connects to my DB and retrives information from a db named login and a table named news. The problem is that it doesn't post the info even though it connects. Heres my code:

```
<html>
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'ascent';
$webdb = 'login';
$newstable = 'news';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password); 
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

if (isset($_GET['newsid']))
{
    $id = (int)$_GET['newsid'];
    mysql_select_db($webdb);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='".$id."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); ?>
    <div class='box_two_title'><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>

    <?php 
    echo $row['body'];
    }
    ?>
Hello
</html>
```

Thank you for all your helpful answers so far but it still doesn't post :S

Comment: Don't you need to call `mysql_select_db('webdb')` instead of `connect::selectDB('webdb')`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your error reporting off?? `connect::selectDB('webdb')` should throw an error.
And additionally, you set host,db name in variables and while connecting you put them in quotes. Why?

```
connect::selectDB('webdb');
```

should be

```
mysql_select_db($webdb);
```

And

```
$con = mysql_connect("$host","$user","$password");
```

should be

```
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. But it still doesn't post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting correct value for $id here 
    `if (isset($_GET['newsid']))
    {
        $id = (int)$_GET['newsid'];` and you have a table 'news' with 'title' and 'body' columns then following would work for you.

```
<html>    <head><title> You Title </title></head>    <body>
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'ascent';
$webdb = 'login';
$newstable = 'news';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
<div class='box_two_title'>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['newsid']))
{
    $id = (int)$_GET['newsid'];
    mysql_select_db($webdb);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='".$id."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); ?>
    echo $row['title'];
    echo "</div>";
    echo $row['body'];
}
else
    echo "</div>";
?>    
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can assure you it doesn't. Just an error which says the HTML tag is an error o.O

Comment: Could you see any html error now. Earlier Body was missing @user1644279

Answer (score 0):

If all your variables have the right values, this should work.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "ascent";
    $webdb = "login";
    $newstable = "news";

    $con = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$password"); 
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    if (isset($_GET['newsid']))
    {
        $id = (int)$_GET['newsid'];
        mysql_select_db("$webdb");

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='".$id."'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <div class='box_two_title'><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>

        <?php 
        echo $row['body'];
        }
    }
    ?>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry bro. I could not accept your edit just because of some mistake while trying to accept. Thanks by the way

Answer (score -1):

Try dumping every var on the way. May be you need to loop the `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`